# conectar php 7.4 con sqlserver

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo un problema al tratar de conectar mi aplicacion php con una base de datos sqlserver, la misma me da el error:

> Message: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

e visto en varias preguntas aca que se debe de descargar los drivers de Microsoft para php, realize todos los pasos descritos en esas preguntas y no me funciona, en mi carpeta ext tengo los siguientes dll's
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en mi ph.ini esta de esta forma

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
extension = php_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll
extension = php_pdo.dll 
;extension=php_odbc.dll
;extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sodium
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
```

ya e probado varias formas ero me sigue dando el mismo error, cabe destacar que uso ambiente windows 7 con xampp y php 7.4.9, con el framework codeigniter 3.

Comment: El nombre de la extensión `php_sqlsrv_74_ts.dll` no coincide con el del archivo `php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x86.dll` y, además, debes asegurarte de que sea la arquitectura adecuada (32 o 64 bits), de acuerdo a la instalación de Windows, XAMPP y PHP.

Comment: gracias por la observación, corregiré y verificare todas esas versiones